# Old images are showing after deleted and uploaded new images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, multifile-uploader

Old images are showing after deleted and uploaded new images in fileupload in asp.net mvc. After delete  catch in browser showing  new imges.

Please give my any solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue that after deleting an image and uploading a new image on that path with the same name, your browser displays the old image, then you have to just put this line in your image URL to get latest image:

```
src = ImagePath + "?r=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```